# Hide Area and Iteration Names users don't have permission to view

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have end users going in as stakeholders and adding new work items. we have a long list of areas and iterations.

I have created a custom group and denied them access to all areas and iterataions except the one they need but when they go create workitem, they can still see all the areas and iterations.

Yes, they cannot save workitem under an area/iteration that they don't have access to but is there a way to display only those areas and iterations that they have access to?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such [work item rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx) by default to hide Area and Iteration Names, you would need to customize your own work item control. The source below can help you start how to customize a work item control:

https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/